# Buckingham-$\Pi$ theorem application: the case of only 0 or 1 dimensionless groups?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

In dimensional analysis, we might consider a problem like:

$$ f(q_1, q_2, ..., q_{n-1}) = q_{n} $$

where $q_i$ are physical quantities of interest. In order to determine how many $\Pi$ groups can be formed, we consider how many "fundamental" quantities are present in the problem. Let us say there are $k$ such fundamental quantities, then we will have $j = n - k$ dimensionless groups, and we can write the above relationship as:

$$ f(\Pi_1, \Pi_2, ..., \Pi_{n-k-1}) = \Pi_{n-k}$$

So consider this in the case of an example, the equation of motion in a 1-D overdamped system, with $\eta$ being the viscosity (dimensions $MT^{-1}$), velocity $\rm{d}x/\rm{d}t$ with units $LT^{-1}$, and force $F$ with units $MLT^{-2}$:

$$\eta \frac{\rm{d}x}{\rm{d}t} = F$$

Or, I can rewrite the equation in a form more familiar in the context of dimensional analysis, where don't care about the actual relationship between quantities:
$$ f(\eta, \frac{\rm{d}x}{\rm{d}t}, F) = 0$$

Here, we have $n = 3$ variables, and one may say that we also have $k = 3$ fundamental dimensions $M$, $L$ and $T$. Then, we have $j = 0$! What now?

$$ f(1, 1, 1) = 0$$

> What is dimensional analysis telling me here? **Is dimensional analysis telling me that I can write the relationship between variables in a totally dimensionless form?**

Okay, maybe I can dance around this by saying that I really only have $k = 2$ fundamental dimensions, if I let them be $MT^{-1} = [\eta]$, and $LT^{-1} = [\dot{x}]$. Okay, so now I have $j = 1$, so I can form one $\Pi$ group, let me call it $\Pi_0$. Skipping the work, $\Pi_0$ will correspond to $F = \eta\dot{x}$.

> This is a major hint that dimensional analysis is telling me something really interesting. In cases where we have $j \leq 0$, we can redefine "fundamental dimensions" to have $j > 0$. Then, dimensional analysis gives us a...major hint about how the variables are related? **I am sure there is a better (more insightful) way to put what I have I just learned -- but what is it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a mistake in saying

> Here, we have $n = 3$ variables, and one may say that we also have $k = 3$ fundamental dimensions $M$, $L$ and $T$.

but it's a subtle one.

To see why the implication does not hold, consider three different variables, with dimensions $[A]=ML/T$, $[B]=ML/T$ and $[C]=ML/T$. Here you have three variables, and three independent dimensions $M$, $L$ and $T$... but of course you cannot infer from their dimensions alone that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are themselves independent. In my example, $n=3$, $k=1$, I can form $n-k=2$ independent pi groups, $B/A$ and $C/A$, and any physically meaningful equation $f(A,B,C)=0$ can be rephrased as $F(B/A,C/A)=0$. You can see how it would go if you add more variables $D,E,\ldots$ with the same dimensionality.

(Note that this is quite a common situation. For example, $B$ and $C$ might be the momentum of two particles which are joined in a collision to give a total momentum $A$. The correct relationship between them is then $F(b,c)=b+c-1=0$.)

The way to test for this is via the dimensionality matrix. In your case, with $[F]=ML/T^2$, $[\eta]=M/T$ and $[v]=L/T$, the dimensionality matrix is
$$
D=\begin{array}{cl}
\begin{array}{ccc}F&\eta&v\end{array} & \\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & -1 & -1 \end{array}\right).
&\begin{array}{c} M\\ L\\ T \end{array}
\end{array}
$$
Its rank is $k=2$, which means that you really only have two independent dimensionalities. Any two will do, but the clearest choice is probably $[\eta]$ and $[v]$, in which case $[F]=[\eta][v]$ is obviously dependent. Since there's $k=2$ independent dimensions and $n=3$ variables, you can form $n-k=1$, i.e. a single pi group, which is $F/\eta v$ or its inverse. Your initial physically-meaningful equation $g(F,\eta,v)=F-\eta v=0$ can thus be rephrased as $$G(F/\eta v)=F/\eta v-1=0.$$

---

Note in particular that **the pi groups need to be dimensionless**. This is the whole point of the pi theorem and the game doesn't really make sense unless you do that. Thus

> Skipping the work, $\Pi_0$ will correspond to $F = \eta\dot{x}$.

is not correct.

Similarly,

> cases where $j=n-k<0$

don't make sense. You cannot encompass $k>n$ independent dimensions using only $n$ variables. This is a fundamental fact of linear algebra: a set of $n$ vectors (in [dimensionality space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174521/is-0-mathrmm-dimensionless/174529#174529)) can only span a subspace of dimension $k\leq n$.

It may be worthwhile exploring the other end of the dimensionality scale to clarify what's going on - the case where $n=k$. Here all your dimensions are physically independent - you might have a length, a time and a mass, say. There is then nothing you can say about them that will be physically meaningful, and you can't form a single pi group. The only allowed statement is $F()\equiv0=0$, which is an empty statement. You can define *new* variables (like, say, momentum) but until you do you're stuck with nothing.