# Is there something special about the 7 fundamental quantities or are they just convention?

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, si-units, metrology

I mean could we do as good with any fewer (or more) fundamental quantities, or is seven really a magical number when it comes to them?

Comment: You could find this easily. There are many obvious hints: The luminosity definitions are completely disconnected from anything else. The definition of temperature is also completely not-needed because we should be measuring temperature with energy units, eliminating Boltzmann's constant $k_B$ in the process.

Comment: As long as nobody points out a reference to PSE, this is an interesting question.

Comment: Please be clear if you are referring to the seven [base SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units). They are not commonly referred to as "fundamental quantities" in my part of the physics world. If referring to base units, then the question is related to: ["Why are there seven SI base units?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294353/145491), ["To what extent are quantities fundamental?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69066/145491), ["Are the 7 base quantities in SI system really independent?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217732/145491)